# Python: get items from list between 2 known items

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to get all items from a python list that are between 2 items. The algorithm must warp through the whole array.

For instance:

I have a string like `"Mo-Fr"`
and I want to end up with a list:

`[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday]`

but I want it to also work this way:

`string = "Fr-Mo"`

`list = Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday`

my code looks at the moment like this:

```
string = 'Mo-Fr'
days_order = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So']
days_dict = {'Mo' : 'Montag',
             'Di' : 'Dienstag',
             'Mi' : 'Mittwoch',
             'Do' : 'Donnerstag',
             'Fr' : 'Freitag',
             'Sa' : 'Samstag',
             'So' : 'Sonntag',}
days = string.split('-')
days = [days_order.index(day) for day in days]
days_list = [days_dict[day] for day in days_order if    days_order.index(day) in range(days[0], days[1] + 1)]
```

So my code works fine if the string looks like "Mo-Fr" but of course doesn't work with "Fr-Mo". 
Any ideas how to get this working in a clean way?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be an occasion where a good ol' fashioned while loop is the cleanest solution.

Comment: You could store the days order to be integers 0-6 for then you will be able to compare and then re order them.

Comment: use the module operator to get a secuence constrained to 0-6 . This code for i in range(10):   print i%7 produces for i in range(10):   print i%7 produces this output   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to double the `days_order` list so that it contains all rotations of the weekdays:

```
>>> days_order = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'] * 2
```

then get the start/end indexes like this:

```
>>> string = 'Fr-Mo'
>>> days = string.split('-')
>>> start = days_order.index(days[0])
>>> end = days_order.index(days[1], start + 1) + 1
```

and finally build the list of days like this:

```
>>> [days_dict[day] for day in days_order[start:end]]
['Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag']
```

Comment: That's what I said, 24 minutes ago. :) Although, I'm doing the second indexing step on a sliced list, rather than providing a starting index.

Comment: thanks for this answer thats based on my example... its working great

Comment: Its the only solution in here that works for 'Di-Di' - well done.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is to use two copies of the `days_order` list, and then slice that list in two steps.

```
days_order = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So']
days_dict = {
    'Mo' : 'Montag',
    'Di' : 'Dienstag',
    'Mi' : 'Mittwoch',
    'Do' : 'Donnerstag',
    'Fr' : 'Freitag',
    'Sa' : 'Samstag',
    'So' : 'Sonntag',
}

def daylist(days):
    first, last = days.split('-')

    days = days_order * 2
    i = days.index(first)
    days = days[i:]

    i = days.index(last)
    days = days[:i+1]
    return [days_dict[s] for s in days]

s = "Mo-Fr"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Fr-Mo"
print s, daylist(s)
```

**output**

```
Mo-Fr ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag']
Fr-Mo ['Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag']
```

---

The above code just returns a single day if the two given items are identical. If instead a full cycle of days is wanted in such cases then ekhumoro's algorithm can be used.

Here's my version:

```
days_order = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So']
days_dict = {
    'Mo' : 'Montag',
    'Di' : 'Dienstag',
    'Mi' : 'Mittwoch',
    'Do' : 'Donnerstag',
    'Fr' : 'Freitag',
    'Sa' : 'Samstag',
    'So' : 'Sonntag',
}

def daylist(days):
    first, last = days.split('-')

    days = days_order * 2
    i = days.index(first)
    j = days.index(last, i + 1)
    return [days_dict[s] for s in days[i:j+1]]    

s = "Mo-Fr"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Fr-Mo"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Di-Di"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Do-Mi"
print s, daylist(s)
```

**output**

```
Mo-Fr ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag']
Fr-Mo ['Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag']
Di-Di ['Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag']
Do-Mi ['Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch']
```

And here's another approach, this time using modular arithmetic, as suggested in a comment by David Lemon:

```
days_short = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So']
days_long = [
    'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 
    'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag'
]

def daylist(days):
    first, last = days.split('-')

    i = days_short.index(first)
    j = days_short.index(last)
    if j <= i:
        j += 7

    return [days_long[k % 7] for k in range(i, j+1)]

s = "Mo-Fr"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Fr-Mo"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Di-Di"
print s, daylist(s)

s = "Do-Mi"
print s, daylist(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed example based on my code! Working Great! and easy to understand

Comment: @rebeling: Sonic didn't mention in the question that the full day cycle is wanted when the two given days are the same. But I'll add some more code to my answer.

Comment: Yepp, David Lemons approach is a pretty clean one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function for this:

```
def AtoB (string, lst):
    a, b = string.split("-")
    sublist = []
    i = lst.index(a)
    while lst[i] != b:
        sublist.append(lst[i])
        i+=1
        i%=len(lst)
    return sublist + [b]
```

Use it like:

```
days = AtoB(string, days_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the days_order just once:

```
for from_to in ['Di-Sa', 'Fr-Mi', 'Di-Di']:

    start_matched, collect_for_buffer = False, True
    head, buffer, tail = [], [], []
    _from, _to = from_to[-2:], from_to[:2]

    for x in days_order:

        if _from == x:
            tail.append(days_dict[x])
            if start_matched is False:
                tail = buffer + tail
            start_matched = False

        else:
            if start_matched is False and collect_for_buffer:
                buffer.append(days_dict[x])

        if _to == x or start_matched:
            start_matched = True
            head.append(days_dict[x])

    print from_to, head + tail
```

et voila

```
Di-Sa ['Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag']
Fr-Mi ['Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch']
Di-Di ['Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag']
```