# Python: get all items from a list between 2 known string or Indexes

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am trying to find all the items between two given indexes. 
for eg: i have list that looks like this:

```
mylist = ['ABC', 'COMMENT', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123', 'COMMENT','GONOW','MAKE','COMMENT', 'YES','COMMENT']
```

i want the output to be show as below:
**Note: Below outputs are the index value between two 'COMMENT'.**

```
First output  :  'YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123'
second output :  'GONOW','MAKE'
third output  :  'YES'
```

I have two thoughts to handle this situation:
1) if i know the search_string as 'COMMENT' then i should be able find everything between two known strings, something like this :

```
string = 'COMMENT'
find_values = mylist[findfirst(comment)-findsecond(comment)]
find_values = mylist[findsecond(comment)-findthird(comment)]
```

2) if i know the index of all 'COMMENT' then i should be able find_all between two known indexs, something like this :

```
idx1_comment = 1
idx2_comment = 6
idx3_comment = 9

print mylist(range(2-5))
print mylist(range(6-8))
```

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Also, i have another request.
For #1 option, if i have list wherein i have a lot of items between strings 'comment' and 'border' then what be the way for that as well?

Btw, i tried following this article, but with no benefit.
[Python: get items from list between 2 known items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018528/python-get-items-from-list-between-2-known-items)

Comment: I am unclear about the output you have printed - what is the input for that output? Can you elaborate on that? And why is it called `first iteration`, `second iteration`? Should it not be `first example`, `second example`, etc?

Comment: corrected and changed the word iteration to output!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on itertools:

```
from itertools import islice

mylist = ['ABC', 'COMMENT', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123', 'COMMENT','GONOW','MAKE','COMMENT', 'YES','COMMENT']

# get indexes of all 'COMMENT'
idx = [i for i,v in enumerate(mylist) if v in [ 'COMMENT']]
print(idx) 

# calculate tuples of data we are interested in: 
#   ( commentIdx+1 , next commentIdx ) for all found ones
idx2 = [ (idx[i]+1,idx[i+1]) for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
print(idx2)

# slice the data out of our list and create lists of the slices
result = [ list(islice(mylist,a,b)) for a,b in idx2]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 9, 11]  # indexes of 'COMMENT'

[(2, 6), (7, 9), (10, 11)]  # Commentindex +1 + the next one as tuple

[['YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123'], ['GONOW', 'MAKE'], ['YES']]
```

You could also skip `idx2`:

```
result = [ list(islice(mylist,a,b)) for a,b in ((idx[i]+1,idx[i+1]) for i in range(len(idx)-1))]
```

---

As for your 2nd question - which should probably be solved by yourself or posted as seperate question:

It depends on the data - do they intermix (`C = COMMENT, B = BORDER`) ?

```
[ C, 1, 2 , C , 3 , B , 4 , B, 5,  C ]
```

Best probably to try it yourself or post a new question with sample data and wanted output. The above one could be

`[ [1,2],[3],[4] ]` or `[ [1,2],[3],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]` or something in between - the first uses strict C-C and B-B and no C-B or B-C matches. The latter allowes C-B and B-C as well as C-......-C ignoring/removing B's in between

Comment: This was my approach #2, great i would prefer this method ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply iterate the list once:

```
result = []
sublist = []

separators = ('COMMENT', 'BORDER')
mylist = ['ABC', 'COMMENT', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123', 'COMMENT','GONOW','MAKE','COMMENT', 'YES','COMMENT', 'BORDER', 'FOO', '123']

for x in mylist:
    if x in separators:
        if sublist:
            result.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
    else:
        sublist.append(x)
result.append(sublist)

print (result)
```

Returns:

```
[['ABC'], ['YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123'], ['GONOW', 'MAKE'], ['YES'], ['FOO', '123']]
```

Comment: is there a way we can remove the first ['ABC'] , it should start from the first thing right after one of the separators. Nothing before that should be captured.

Comment: `print (result[1:])`

Comment: `mylist[:] = mylist[mylist.index('COMMENT'):] ` will strip anything from the list before the first COMMENT

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to filter out the strings between two predefined strings, this code will do:

```
def filter_output_between_strings(input: [str], separator: str):
    separator_indexes = [index for index, word in enumerate(input) if word == separator]
    for example_index, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(separator_indexes[:-1], separator_indexes[1:]), start=1):
        print('Example: {}: {}'.format(example_index, input[start + 1:end]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = ['ABC', 'COMMENT', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123', 'COMMENT', 'GONOW', 'MAKE', 'COMMENT', 'YES', 'COMMENT']
    filter_output_between_strings(input, 'COMMENT')
```

Output:

```
Example: 1: ['YES', 'YES', 'NO', '123']
Example: 2: ['GONOW', 'MAKE']
Example: 3: ['YES']
```

Comment: Personal opinion, it's really hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: getting syntax error at :     def filter_output_between_strings(input:[str], separator: str):
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   ---> for input : [str] ... is it meant for py3 ?

Comment: Yes, the type hinting only works for Python 3.4 and up. For Python 2, the type hinting (the types in the arguments after the colon) should be removed, it should work then.